# XSLT select when specific tag w/attribute exists?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm struggling to modify a legacy xslt file to do something simple but I'm not very good in the language.  I'm trying to modify a variable definition that checks the value of `<EVENTTYPE>foo</EVENTTYPE>`.  I need it to also match when a  tag exists.  This is the xslt variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="isFoo" select="$EventType = 'foo'" />
```

This works when I have an `<EventType>foo</EventType>` in the xml file.  However, let's say I don't have this tag and instead this is my xml:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <bar type='baz' other='stuff'>
            ...
        </bar>
    </b>
</a>
```

I need `isFoo` to be true if there's a `<bar type='baz'>` tag somewhere in the file (it has to be a `bar` with an `type='baz'` on it).

What I need to change my `<xsl:variable ...>` to above to be true when `<bar type='baz'>` is present?

Comment: If the expression is really `$EventType = 'foo'`, that is, it uses another variable, then consider to make the sample complete by showing the declaration of the other variable as well.

Comment: Add `or //bar[@type='baz']` to your existing expression.